# Is there any way in django to include some module in every page

Tags: python, django

In my django app i have to include logger in almost every page around 30 different files like this

```
import logging
logger_test = logging.getLogger('test')

logger_test.info('test')
```

Is there any way that gets included in all files and i can just run

```
logger_test.info('test')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would prefer just putting `logger_test` somewhere and using `from myapp import logger_test`. One extra line per file is much less likely to wreak havoc than the following.

You can do this using the appropriately named [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/builtins.html?highlight=builtins#module-builtins) module (py2 `__builtins__`). Just add the logger to the builtins module anywhere, putting this in settings.py is probably a good choice.

```
import builtins
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('test')
setattr(builtins, 'logger_test', logger)
```

Now every module will have `logger_test` available. A last warning, this is a truly terrible idea.

Comment: thanks for that , i just keep it during developement and then will remove it